# How to get imdb episode ids using python web crawler with selenium in pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, imdb

Hi please am using python selenium in pycharm to scrapy imdb data for episodes id am able to retrieve, some data using the below code to print "main.text" data such as episode name , description, rating for the complete season but when i run it program with **print(newData.text)** i am getting error **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'** and when i run it without text that is **print(newData)** i get result as **[ ]**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1405406/episodes?season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1")
try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "episodes_content"))
    )
    links = main.find_elements_by_tag_name("image")
    for image in links:
        newData = image.find_elements_by_tag_name("data_const")
    print(main.text)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Here is the inspect element i am using to check for the tag that has the link

```
  <div class="image">
<a href="/title/tt1478775/?ref_=ttep_ep3" title="Friday Night Bites" itemprop="url"> <div data-const="tt1478775" class="hover-over-image zero-z-index ">
<img class="zero-z-index" alt="Friday Night Bites" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg1OTc3ODEyOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDE2MDY4Mg@@._V1_UX224_CR0,0,224,126_AL_.jpg" width="224" height="126">
<div>S1, Ep3</div>
</div>
```

i have tried using all available data type to get the value of the data_const to print but none are working
here is a list of tags i have tried
**--image.find_elements_by_tag_name("data_const"),** **--image.find_elements_by_class_name("data_const"),** **--image.find_elements_by_name("data_const"),** **--image.find_elements_by_id("data_const"),** **--image.find_elements_by_link_text("data_const"),**
**--image.find_elements_by_css_selector("data_const"),**

Comment: _image_, _data_const_ no such tags on the page. data_const is the attribute of HTML tag, first understand the difference between the attributes and the tags. Also there is No tag name as image, its img. Not sure what data you want to scrape. Since that tag name you passed as parameter not exist it returned nothing but the empty list.

Comment: the data am trying to retrieve is the imdb id of each episode i can retrieve it also using the link in the title that is **<a href** but how can i use it to retrieve the the link if possible